# What can i use in place of TimeSeconds() in mql5?

Tags: mql5

I used `TimeSeconds(opening time of any candle selected)` in mql4 to track the current seconds as it is changing. i used it to set my Alert() to sound only twice. Now i want to do the same thing in Mql5, then i discover that mql5 does not have `TimeSeconds()`. How can i go about it?

The following code was what i used in mql4.

```
datetime myTime = iTime(_Symbol,_Period,0);
int currentMinute = TimeMinute(TimeCurrent());
int openMinutesOfLastCandle = TimeSeconds(myTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#ifdef __MQL5__
   int TimeSeconds(const datetime date)
     {
      MqlDateTime dt;
      TimeToStruct(time,dt);
      return dt.sec;
     }
#endif
```

Alternative would be to use `TimeCurrent()%60` to get seconds.